# Macbook : Replacing RAM while on hibernate?

Tags: mac, memory, macbook, upgrade, sleep

Although it is implied that all the content in memory is written to the hard drive under forced hibernation (using pmset), I'm still unsure whether it is safe to upgrade my macbook's memory during that state or not. I don't want to shut it off completely as it's too much of a bother to re-open all the programs I'm working with ; has anyone tried this before ?

Comment: Upgrading as in: increasing the RAM size?

Comment: I would recommend against doing any kind of non hot-pluggable hardware changes while the OS is hibernated or the computer is on.

Comment: Really? Is it more of a bother to have a broken computer? As infrequently as you upgrade RAM, why not take the time to turn the thing off? I mean seriously, if I were doing this, I'd be careful about **static** electricity. No **way** would I have **actual** electricity running through my $1,000 machine.

Comment: @trip0d199: excellent advice for second part (while computer is on). Even changing hot-pluggable hardware to hibernated computer is problematic for OS, but not for hardware in any way.

Comment: Why are people upvoting @trip0d199 and @Nathan Long? They don't seem to know what hibernation is. Hibernation, at least on Macs, is when your memory contents are completely written out to disk and your computer is COMPLETELY off. The only difference between a hibernation and a normal shutdown is the contents of the disk (and perhaps a few bits in NVRAM).

Comment: @spiff : Exactly why I asked this ; the computer should be fully shut down, only to re-read the contents from the hard drive (at least that's how it is done in linux) upon booting, yet I wanted to hear from someone who has experienced this before. Anyway, I was too afraid to take the risk so I had shut it down completely before upgrading it.

Comment: I had no problem with upgrading my MBP's memory from 2x2GB to 2x4GB when it was in  hibernate mode.
But when you turn your MAC after replacing RAMS, you can't see the new total amount of RAMs in both Activity Monitor and "About this MAC" window.
After i restarted the MAC, the real amount of memory was there.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't try plugging new RAM while the machine is on or hibernated (or replacing one)...
Anyways, even if it works and the machine doesn't freeze or have some electrical problem, you'll probably have to reboot to be able to use the new RAM.

Answer (score 1):

That cannot work. It will crash for sure.

And if by any divine intervention it would, the machine would probably not be able to see the extra RAM until you would reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for certain but I once added some more RAM to a hibernated laptop running Windows XP and the machine freaked out big time when it started up!

Answer (score 0):

Changing hard disk to another one or to SSD during hibernate freaks Mac OS X and Windows 7 completely (fail and automatic reboot). Mac OS X can't handle changing memory. It as well as other operating systems rely on memory layout, which changes then.

If you hibernate your computer, it's not hot-plugging. Static electricity is your only problem.